# Is there a way to create dynamic documents using MS Word and SQL queries?

Tags: sql, latex, ms-word, sweave

I'm writing a document using MS Word 2010. For this document (a written report) I would like to integrate SQL queries which fetch data from SQL Server database. Data in the database is changing all the time. Is there a way to "compile" or "run" this document to get the most recent results from the database into this document (text in this doc should remain intact)? I'm looking for a same kind of functionality which is provided by [Sweave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweave) when writing Latex documents.

Comment: Also, you can embed an Excel object which itself pulls from SQL Server.

Comment: You can use [pod](http://appyframework.org/pod.html) if export OO to MSWord is a solution for you.

Comment: you can write some VBA code inside the word document, to do whatever you want (query, select, update, ecc...)

Answer (score 0):

If you understand Sweave (and [R](http://www.r-project.org/)) then you can use R to produce either HTML, ODF, PDF or graphics / plain text and open them in Word (or import into a Word Document) and include SQL query results using [RODBC](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html).  I'd recommend looking at [Knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) for producing HTML and/or plaintext and [ODFWeave](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odfWeave/index.html) for producing ODF files.

Comment: Yes, I know that but this includes manual work, and R and Sweave. I was looking for a similar solution for MS word without external tools. It seems that there is no such possibility.